# How to propositionalize a relational data set for clustering analysis?

Tags: clustering, data-mining, dataset

I am working with a data set of students and their courses for a single semester, attempting to cluster based on the courses & various other attributes where "courses" are the "many" side of a one-to-many relationship. If it matters, I have R, JMP and RapidMiner at my disposal.

I can propositionalize the data set in into a single table structure in a few ways, but nothing that makes sense to me for one reason or another:

I can structure the data set with multiple polynomial attributes that can take the value of any course name, e.g.,

```
STUDENT course1 course2 course3 course4 course5 GPA TEST1 TEST2 TEST3
   1     ENGL2   MATH1   HIST1   ACCT1   BIOL2  3.2  87    342   18
   2     ENGL1   CHEM2   COMP1   HIST1    N/A   3.5  93    312   22
```

etc. But the order of the courses doesn't matter, e.g., it doesn't matter if HIST1 appears in course3 or course4.

Alternatively, I could split out all courses into binary values, e.g.,

```
STUDENT  GPA TEST1 TEST2 TEST3 ACCT1 BIOL2 CHEM2 COMP1 ENGL1 ENGL2 HIST1 MATH1
   1     3.2   87   342   18     1     1     0     0     0     1     1     1
   2     3.5   93   312   22     0     0     1     1     1     0     1     0
```

However, in the full data set this would result in about 400 attributes. That seems pretty inefficient, and data sets with far fewer attributes have choked my system's 16gb of RAM.

So, I'm not sure how to proceed. Any insight on how such one-to-many structures are commonly dealt with would be useful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that your software will typically turn "polynomial" attributes into arrays of booleans anyway. Well, boolean in mathematical terms; they'll typically be stored as double precision numbers. 400 columns isn't small, but by modern standards it isn't incredibly huge either. 16GB should easily be able to handle that, if you're doing K-means clustering or supervised learning.

What may have been blowing up your memory is trying to work with *distance matrices* of 400 or more variables, which might happen if you're using hierarchical clustering methods. That's something quite distinct, since a distance matrix of $M$ variables is an $M \times M$ square matrix. Hierarchical clustering algorithms also tend to be $O(M^2)$ or worse (I think? It's been some time since I used them) so running times quickly get out of hand.

Comment: I'll give it a shot... the memory issues for data sets with attributes > 50 were in RapidMiner, mostly using neural net based models and related, such as Self Organizing Maps. I might be able to reduce the attribute set by using generic "Other" attributes for courses that appear in less than 1% of the population.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach seems reasonable to me.

400 booleans doesn't seem like too many features if they are correctly represented as booleans you should be able to store them in 400 bits of information = 50bytes.

Therefore if you have 1 million rows, you're talking roughly 50MB data. Should leave you lots of elbow room for your favourite learning algorithm?